# spring cloud config server - no decrypt on cipher value

Tags: spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-dataflow

- Spring Cloud Data Flow Server Cloudfoundry - 1.0.0.RELEASE
- Spring Cloud Config Server - 1.1.3

This is a weird behavior.  We are observing a spring cloud stream application deployed into Spring Cloud Data Flow, and the bound config server instance is reading {cipher} prepended values from the properties file as plain text values and not attempting to decrypt them.

I see something like this while debugging the application:

```
dbPassword = {cipher}poiquetrpoiuqef345ja678d789ghpasygsrytsdkghosityserthsdgh
```

Instead of something like this:

```
dbPassword = superSecret
```

Everything else appears to be in order in terms of how the Config Server is configured, and the fact it is loading the properties file from our Git repo.  It is just not decrypting the cipher values.  What simple thing are we forgetting?

Comment: Reading through spring-cloud's Brixton.SR6 [docs](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Brixton.SR6/#_encryption_and_decryption), you'd need to have `spring-security-rsa` in the classpath to decrypt the encrypted properties. If you don't have it, please retry testing with it.

Comment: Yep, that was the correct additional dependency that was needed.  Thanks for the response.